# input value should update on span value changes once file uploads

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, buefy, vuejs3

After uploading an image file, I want the `<input>`'s value to reflect my `<span>` value. However, only after I click the `<a>` tag does the `<input>` change its value, not automatically on the `<span>`'s change as desired.

I want the `<span>`-change to update the `<input>`'s value.

```html
<input
  v-model="data.filename"
  class="input"
  type="text"
  placeholder
  readonly
/>

<b-upload v-model="file">
  <span class="ss" v-if="file">{{ file.name }}</span>
  <a class="button is-orange has-text-white" @click="valuedata">
    <span>Upload</span>
  </a>
</b-upload>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      file: null,
      data: {
        filename: ''
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    valuedata() {
      this.data.filename = this.file.name
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

The screenshot above shows the results after file upload/selection. While the `<span>`'s value updates correctly, the `<input>`'s value however remains the same. Its value updates only after clicking the anchor tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `b-upload` component has an `input` event that is fired when a file is selected:

[image: b-upload Events API]

You could add an `input`-handler that sets `data.filename` to the selected file's name:

```html
<b-upload @input="onFileSelected">
```

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    onFileSelected(file) {
      this.data.filename = file.name
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ExPxBJR?editors=1010)

Comment: @TechDev No problem :)